# What is an existing library for making queries with the relational model?

Tags: database, relational-algebra

I'm looking for a simple, high level library (implemented in python would be nice) for handling the [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra).  Alternatively, an existing SQL implementation might have support for these queries.

For example, if the relation schema of the `account` relation is `(account id, name, balance)`, I'd like to input the expression here

> 'http://www.mathtran.org/cgi-bin/mathtran?tex=\pi_{name}(\sigma_{account_id>3}(\text{account}))'

and not have to worry about getting back a multiset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dee, a python library including project, rename, join, restriction (select), and even divide...

http://www.quicksort.co.uk/

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a pretty simple C-based relational algebra library.](http://tclral.sourceforge.net/)